# Setting nested data structures from helm command line?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm installing the [prometheus-redis-exporter Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-redis-exporter). Its `Deployment` object has a way to inject annotations:

```
# deployment.yaml
...
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.annotations | indent 8 }}
```

Typically if I was providing a values file, I could just do this:

```
# values.yaml
annotations:
  foo: bar
  bash: baz
```

And then install the chart with:

```
helm install --values values.yaml
```

However, in some cases it is more simple for me to specify these values on the command line with `--set` instead, I'm just not sure how I would specify a nested set like that.

How can I set the above `annotations` object when installing a helm chart on the commandline:

```
helm install --set <what_goes_here>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `helm` docu has a section [The Format and Limitations of --set](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set), which contains what you are looking for.

`--set outer.inner=value` results in:

```
outer:
  inner: value
```

Therefore your whole `helm` command looks like this:

```
helm install --set annotations.foo=bar,annotations.bash=baz stable/prometheus-redis-exporter
```

Answer (score 17):

Just to add, if you are looking to override a key with a "." in the key name, add a back slash ("\") before the ".".

for example, with values (taken from grafana):

```
grafana.ini:
  server:
    root_url: https://my.example.com
```

To edit the `root_url` value we would pass 
`--set grafana\.ini.server.root_url=https://your.example.com`

Comment: Showing how to escape the dot with the backslash saved me some time. Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: It saved me as well with nodeSelector setup `name: prometheusOperator.nodeSelector\.super.cash-worker_group-name`, `value: monitoring`